# dateNow = datetime.datetime.now() causes AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'" while calculating age

Tags: python, datetime

Trying to figure out how to get the current date to lock in as a variable to subtract from the self.birthday that is input. I have looked at various examples and links to no avail...suggestions?

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = None


#getName returns the name of the person         
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

#setBirthday sets their Birthday to a date
    def setBirthday(self):
        day = raw_input('Please enter the date of the month you were born on here ->')
        month = raw_input('Please enter the month of the year you were born on here ->')
        year = raw_input('Please enter the year you were born on here ->')
        self.birthday = int(day),  int(month), int(year)
        print self.birthday

#getAge returns how many days old the individual is     
    def getAge(self):
        dateNow = datetime.datetime.now()
        dateBirth = self.birthday
        timedelta = dateNow - dateBirth
        timedelta = self.daysOld
        print self.daysOld
```

Error message is "dateNow = datetime.datetime.now()
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'"

I have tried the following

```
datetime.date.today()
```

with no success

resources I'm using:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/

Comment: Have you tried `datetime.now()` since you are already importing `datetime.datetime` as `datetime`

Comment: datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.now()` refers to a method (`now`) of a class (2nd `datetime`) of a library (1st `datetime`), however you didn't import the entire library, just the single class (`from datetime import datetime`). Either import the entire library or call on the class without referring to the library.

Comment: now I'm getting this error...timedelta = dateNow - dateBirth
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'tuple' , so I need to probably cast the data I would think..

Comment: The other variable also needs to be a `datetime` object for time addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
n= date.today()
```

I will give you the current date in string format then use `split()`.